# how to get max date from arrays of objects

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to get the max date of the dates from an array of objects  , if dates are null it will just return null right now it returns `--MAXDATE Thu Jan 01 1970 08:00:00 GMT+0800 (.... Standard Time)`. if there no max date from the arrays of object then return max as null .

Any idea guys ? Thanks.

#code

```
  const maxDate = new Date(
            Math.max(
              ...data.map(element => {
                return new Date(element.MeasureDate);
              }),
            ),
          );
             console.log('--MAXDATE' , maxDate)
```

#sample data

=

```
[
  {
    "Address": 25,
    "AlertType": 1,
    "Area": "North",
    "MeasureDate": "2019-02-01T00:01:01.001Z",
    "MeasureValue": -1
  },
  {
    "Address": 26,
    "AlertType": 1,
    "Area": "West",
    "MeasureDate": "2016-04-12T15:13:11.733Z",
    "MeasureValue": -1
  },
  {
    "Address": 25,
    "AlertType": 1,
    "Area": "North",
    "MeasureDate": "2017-02-01T00:01:01.001Z",
    "MeasureValue": -1
  }
          .
          .
          .
]
```

#sample data2 - output is 2019-02-01T00:01:01.001Z

=

```
[
  {
    "Address": 25,
    "AlertType": 1,
    "Area": "North",
    "MeasureDate": "2019-02-01T00:01:01.001Z",
    "MeasureValue": -1
  },
  {
    "Address": 26,
    "AlertType": 1,
    "Area": "West",
    "MeasureDate": null,
    "MeasureValue": -1
  },
  {
    "Address": 25,
    "AlertType": 1,
    "Area": "North",
    "MeasureDate": null,
    "MeasureValue": -1
  }
          .
          .
          .
]
```

#sample data3 - output is null

=

```
[
  {
    "Address": 25,
    "AlertType": 1,
    "Area": "North",
    "MeasureDate": null,
    "MeasureValue": -1
  },
  {
    "Address": 26,
    "AlertType": 1,
    "Area": "West",
    "MeasureDate": null,
    "MeasureValue": -1
  },
  {
    "Address": 25,
    "AlertType": 1,
    "Area": "North",
    "MeasureDate": null,
    "MeasureValue": -1
  }
          .
          .
          .
]
```

Comment: You are passing the *string* `"null"` for nulls?  Why?

Comment: sorry my bad typo , please check again

Comment: Hi @Enve , I have no issue of the date or format or something , my concern is if when comparing dates if there is no max date because some of the value are null then just return null

Comment: How about `if (maxDate === "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"){ maxDate = null }`?

Comment: I think that is a bit absurd solution Sir

Comment: OK I accept that. That is how most of my programs are put together (sadly)!

Comment: It returns that date because `Math.max(null) === 0`. Extract the `Math.max` call to another variable and do a simple check: `maxDate = max === 0 ? null : new Date(max)`. Or filter the null values from the array and don't run the `Math.max` call at all if the length is 0.

Comment: I dont mean it in a bad way Sir , I am sorry

Comment: @Enve , comparing max to 0 would never be possible since if dates are null the method will automatically return Thu Jan 01 1970 08:00:00 GMT+0800

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one approach:

```
function maxMeasureDate(arr: Array<{ [k: string]: any, MeasureDate: string | null }>) {
    const maxTimestamp = Math.max(...arr.
        map(x => x.MeasureDate !== null ? Date.parse(x.MeasureDate) : -Infinity)
    );
    return (maxTimestamp !== -Infinity) ? new Date(maxTimestamp) : null;
}
```

We use [the `Date.parse()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) to get the timestamp as a number, and then use [the `Math.max()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) on the results to get the maximum one.  Then we pass this maximum to [the `Date()` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date).  We have to account for values where the `MeasureDate` property is `null`, and we do this by returning [the `-Infinity` value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/NEGATIVE_INFINITY) which is the smallest possible number.  This is what comes out of `Math.max()` if you pass it no input, also.  So the only way `-Infinity` will come out of `Math.max()` is if there are no non-`null` values of the `MeasureDate` property.  Thus at the very end we check for `-Infinity` and if it is that value we return `null`.

Let's test it out:

```
const sample1 = [
    {
        "Address": 25,
        "AlertType": 1,
        "Area": "North",
        "MeasureDate": "2019-02-01T00:01:01.001Z",
        "MeasureValue": -1
    },
    {
        "Address": 26,
        "AlertType": 1,
        "Area": "West",
        "MeasureDate": "2016-04-12T15:13:11.733Z",
        "MeasureValue": -1
    },
    {
        "Address": 25,
        "AlertType": 1,
        "Area": "North",
        "MeasureDate": "2017-02-01T00:01:01.001Z",
        "MeasureValue": -1
    }
]
console.log(maxMeasureDate(sample1)); // Date: "2019-02-01T00:01:01.001Z" 

const sample2 = [
    {
        "Address": 25,
        "AlertType": 1,
        "Area": "North",
        "MeasureDate": "2019-02-01T00:01:01.001Z",
        "MeasureValue": -1
    },
    {
        "Address": 26,
        "AlertType": 1,
        "Area": "West",
        "MeasureDate": null,
        "MeasureValue": -1
    },
    {
        "Address": 25,
        "AlertType": 1,
        "Area": "North",
        "MeasureDate": null,
        "MeasureValue": -1
    }
]
console.log(maxMeasureDate(sample2)); // Date: "2019-02-01T00:01:01.001Z" 

const sample3 = [
    {
        "Address": 25,
        "AlertType": 1,
        "Area": "North",
        "MeasureDate": null,
        "MeasureValue": -1
    },
    {
        "Address": 26,
        "AlertType": 1,
        "Area": "West",
        "MeasureDate": null,
        "MeasureValue": -1
    },
    {
        "Address": 25,
        "AlertType": 1,
        "Area": "North",
        "MeasureDate": null,
        "MeasureValue": -1
    }
];
console.log(maxMeasureDate(sample3)); // null
```

Looks good.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=19&ssc=24&pln=18&pc=24#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAWwIYA8CyBTVBnEAJ2wBFUpsAKVQwgLkQEFbUBPAHgG9EBtAawZ4ohGGADmAXQaowrADSIc+IqXLZBw0WMQAfRGBAAbQ4gC+APgCUiTgFgAUIieIICISgwAVGMmxDUyAAOiAC8iuQAFgB0aOiUUQk0hFEOzmkegZTooeaI6FFKBMRkFIgAhCFhBsaIAPyIJdhRgTR4VPmFKo3WDAC0AJJgwKIwUKyWqc6WANyTTsRQREiUsd6+-kHllYgDQyNj1vVg2ADuDWorXj5+UAGBPfpGhrP2pg4OrmDueHeG2ACMoV4cxsILSACJGAATKHEPB4cEMABMAFY5GDnJC-oQoJ5WIFsIjEP90Y50k5IcRUETwQA5OA4iLg0nkimdYpqGlIgAM-wAnL1uUjBf9PNzuXReZL-lFxf8AFrMjFs3BFbAANVQhhAhL6-xBphZzjsZPJkJhcIRyIAbEazYxsbj8briXb0pTcDSAOo3JWm93s1QULm862CgAsvX+SM8-xRdH+AGYEzKAOyJxOKt0QwOa7UuqMGt0m1mIc2wvxWxCo7OYh3YHF4glEknKsvMT0MOkMqBM2sq5Qc4Ndnn-VOC4W8sUSqW82W8rNt8G5rU6omF-1vewSD5uOB-KKGOBiS5YVVdC4-IJ-f6WGaIAD0D-OFBHvIFQpF0+l0vnCvBiDvPYnzfL82BIkCPAgiWrLlpaRI1ku9aNs6Lb9u2VI0vSjJ+qWy7nkOLrgqOH6TqK4o-nOcqLv6OYERqq4Fvqm7FkhFqVghtpIY6TYuq2tF1phXY+kIuGwYGjREtUhjofhg4Mfm67MWkhrQWxFbwghaLcQ2TrNgw-F4R21JdthvZiWaEmcgw0mySuil6gaDg7sBe4HkeJ6xFZFCUFegR-Eid7TI+z7Ee+E5fhRs4ytRAFASBUCIH5fyJpBakCRS0IaVWiEZe2PGoQZsnGVhPZ9ku3kurZFX0Xma6OSx6VGexmk2sVBX6a6SFCWWIlQBZAb0ZJNlPHZtWMUpRZNbBWXwci2l5Vium8Wh3WdmWZnlYtlVSaNNXyXVTFOduLwgfuTQeaelW+WBiZBSFjzGEBDhAA)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
const data = [
  {
    "Address": 25,
    "AlertType": 1,
    "Area": "North",
    "MeasureDate": "2019-02-01T00:01:01.001Z",
    "MeasureValue": -1
  },
  {
    "Address": 26,
    "AlertType": 1,
    "Area": "West",
    "MeasureDate": "2016-04-12T15:13:11.733Z",
    "MeasureValue": -1
  },
  {
    "Address": 25,
    "AlertType": 1,
    "Area": "North",
    "MeasureDate": "2017-02-01T00:01:01.001Z",
    "MeasureValue": -1
  }
]

const maxDate = data.reduce((max, item) => {
  if (item.MeasureDate) {
    const date = new Date(item.MeasureDate);
    
    if (max)
      max = date > max ? date : max;
    else 
      max = date;
  }
  
  return max;
}, null);

console.log(maxDate)
```